# Turning on contentEditable on a span element is taking text with it and can't clear it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two span elements, the 1st is editable the 2nd is not.

```
<span id="auth-cell-content-1" class="auth-cell-content" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" contentEditable="true"></span>
<span id="auth-cell-content-2" class="auth-cell-content" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" contentEditable="false"></span>
```

What I wish to happen is that when the user enters a single numerical value in the 1st element, then the 2nd element will become focused and be editable. However with JS code, when the 2nd element has `contentEditable` turned "true", then focused the previous number appears in the 2nd element.

JS Code:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    var target = evt.target;
    var targetID = parseInt(target.id.charAt(target.id.length-1))+1;

    var nextTarget = target.id.slice(0, -1)+targetID;

    $("#"+target.id).text(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
    $("#"+target.id).attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $("#"+nextTarget).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $("#"+nextTarget).first().focus();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **onkeyup** instead of **onkeypress**

If you use onkeypress then it'll run the JS code faster than you release the button so basically when you press the button, it also jumps to the next input and insert it because it was pressed. **onkeyup** will fire when you release the button so it won't insert twice.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Szabii97/pen/rNmdZoY) is the working codepen with **onkeyup**

HTML

```
<span id="auth-cell-content-1" class="auth-cell-content" onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" contentEditable="true">RANDOM</span><br>
<span id="auth-cell-content-2" class="auth-cell-content" onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" contentEditable="false">RANDOM</span>
```